# How to get bitcoin wallet or address balance by PHP without any API?

Tags: json, rpc, bitcoin

How can I get bitcoin balance by using PHP?

Keen to get a step by step tutorial.

My server is shared Linux.

Json rpc Client might be the solution but do I need to install daemon on my server. If yes, how can I do that, by SSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this. To learn how to install bitcoind on ubuntu, check the tutorial here: https://github.com/kyledrake/coinpunk/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md#install-and-configure-bitcoind

Make sure you do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` first!

It is also reccomended to run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install git autoconf libtool ntp build-essential
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades
```

You can then use http://jsonrpcphp.org/ (for php) to connect to the daemon and execute daemon commands.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is that possible to use different way( without sudo) because I check my server. It's shared...

Comment: This all depends on your hosting provider. Contact them and ask. These commands NEED ROOT unless your account has ROOT privileges.

Comment: Hi @nahtnam, thank you~ just last question: is there a different way to achieve getting bitcoin balance without using sudo? Thank you~

Comment: Sure you can. You can use simple apis like blockchains and coinbases. If you want a fully functioning QT without running the daemon on your server, check this out: https://blockchain.info/api/json_rpc_api. If you want something simple, check these two out: https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api and https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php